# Exit Trade After X Days

Tags: python, pandas

I am testing a simple trading strategy whereby if the closing price is greater than the upper bollinger band, I buy the underlying stock. I want to automatically close the date after x days have passed since the last buy, but I am struggling to code the logic.

My strategy function is as follows:

```
def strategy(df):
    buy = []
    trade_date = []
    sell = []
    flag = 0
    buy_price = 0
    
    for i in range(0,len(df)):
        
        if df['Close'][i] > df['Upper Bollinger'][i] and flag == 0:
            buy.append(df['Close'][i])
            sell.append(np.nan)
            buy_price = df['Close'][i]
            trade_date.append(df.index[i])
            flag = 1
            
        else:
            buy.append(np.nan)
            sell.append(np.nan)
            trade_date.append(np.nan)
            
    return (buy, sell, trade_date)
```

I have attempted `.ffill()` but this is not used by the function as it is added to the dataframe after the function has ran.

```
strat = strategy(df)
df['Buy'] = strat[0]
df['Sell'] = strat[1]
df['Trade Date'] = strat[2]
df['Trade Date'] = df['Trade Date'].ffill()
```

Is there a way for the strategy() function to locate the date of the last buy, and to determine, when looping through the rows, if x days have passed, to 'sell'?

Comment: This code looks like it could probably be optimised significantly, but it's hard to tell without sample data. Could you please [edit] your question to add some and the expected output from that data.